# Docker compose status: stopping

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to put Flask API app to the docker container. All work fine for building docker image as well running from docker compose except when I will do `docker-compose up -d` it will show status of a docker compose as "stopping" when a container under it shows as "running"

[image]

Current `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.11
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5555
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:5555"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

Docker compose logs:

```
Attaching to python-api_app_1
app_1  | DEBUG:root:Starting app
app_1  |  * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
app_1  |  * Environment: production
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
app_1  |  * Debug mode: on
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5555/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
app_1  | DEBUG:root:Starting app
app_1  | WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 791-950-860
app_1  | DEBUG:root:Starting app
app_1  |  * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
app_1  |  * Environment: production
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
app_1  |  * Debug mode: on
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5555/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
app_1  | DEBUG:root:Starting app
app_1  | WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
app_1  | INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 791-950-860
```

Any tips on that case why it is reported that way?

Comment: did executing into the docker container, making the changes not help? i..e `docker exec -it container_id sh`?

Comment: @DirtyBit yeah - I can access code via terminal but I was looking for something like a "hot update" from an IDE.

Comment: You are copying the files of your app in `/app` and referencing the volume in `/usr/src/app`. Check `/usr/src/app` for the changed files

Comment: Your volume mount goes to an other path than where your app is.

Comment: @KlausD. so I need to change `.:/usr/src/app` to `.:/app` ?

Comment: Just give it a try!

Comment: Show us your folder/file structure!

Comment: @KlausD. ok got it to work with `./app:/app`  but for some reason docker composer status shows it as "stopping" when container shows is as "running"

Comment: The problem is that first you are building your image and then attaching the volume. This means that the app.py is not available at the time of build. Create a "bin" file for app.py which you could copy and create a volume for the rest

Comment: @JackTheKnife what do the logs say? (`docker-compose` and `docker logs container-id`)

Comment: @borisdonchev I have update OP with the log. Both logs are the same.